# TextInputLayout with loading indicator

Tags: android, progress-bar, loading, android-progressbar, material-components-android

Using [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout) from [Material Design library](https://www.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) we can use various [end icon modes](https://www.material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/#pre-packaged-endiconmodes) for password redaction, text clearing and custom mode. Furthermore, if we use any of `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*.ExposedDropdownMenu` styles it will automatically apply special end icon mode that displays open and close chevrons.

Example of various icon modes:

[image: End Icon Modes]

Given the variety of use cases for the end icon, we decided to use a loading indicator in the `InputTextLayout` so that it looks like this:

[image: Loading indicator mode]

How should one proceed to implement it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One can simply set use custom drawable in place of End Icon like this:

```
textInputLayout.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM
textInputLayout.endIconDrawable = progressDrawable
```

The problematic part is getting hold of a loading indicator drawable.

---

### Bad Option 1

There is no public drawable resource we can use for a loading indicator.

There is `android.R.drawable.progress_medium_material` but it is marked private and cannot be resolved in code. Copying the resource and all of its dependent private resources totals into about 6 files (2 drawables + 2 animators + 2 interpolators). That could work but feels quite like a hack.

---

### Bad Option 2

We can use `ProgressBar` to retrieve its `indeterminateDrawable`. The problem with this approach is that the drawable is closely tied to the `ProgressBar`. The indicator is animated only when the `ProgressBar` is visible, tinting one View will also tint the indicator in the other View and probably additional weird behavior.

In similar situations, we can use `Drawable.mutate()` to get a new copy of the drawable. Unfortunately the `indeterminateDrawable` is already mutated and thus `mutate()` does nothing.

What actually worked to decouple the drawable from the `ProgressBar` was a call to `indeterminateDrawable.constantState.newDrawable()`. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState) for more insight.

Anyway, this still feels like a hack.

---

### Good Option 3

Although the drawable resource is marked private we can resolve certain theme attributes to get the system's default loading indicator drawable. The theme defines `progressBarStyle` attribute that references style for `ProgressBar`. Inside of this style is `indeterminateDrawable` attribute that references themed drawable. In code we can resolve the drawable like this:

```
fun Context.getProgressBarDrawable(): Drawable {
    val value = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall, value, false)
    val progressBarStyle = value.data
    val attributes = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.indeterminateDrawable)
    val array = obtainStyledAttributes(progressBarStyle, attributes)
    val drawable = array.getDrawableOrThrow(0)
    array.recycle()
    return drawable
}
```

Great, now we have a native loading indicator drawable without hacks!

---

## Extra measures

### Animation

Now if you plug in the drawable into this code

```
textInputLayout.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM
textInputLayout.endIconDrawable = progressDrawable
```

you will find out that it does not display anything.

Actually, it does display the drawable correctly but the real problem is that it is not being animated. It just happens that at the beginning of the animation the drawable is collapsed into an invisible point.

Unfortunately for us, we cannot convert the drawable to its real type `AnimationScaleListDrawable` because it is in `com.android.internal.graphics.drawable` package.
Fortunately for us, we can type it as `Animatable` and `start()` it:

```
(drawable as? Animatable)?.start()
```

---

### Colors

Another unexpected behavior happens when `TextInputLayout` receives/loses focus. At such moments it will tint the drawable according to colors defined by `layout.setEndIconTintList()`. If you don't explicitly specify a tint list, it will tint the drawable to `?colorPrimary`. But at the moment when we set the drawable, it is still tinted to `?colorAccent` and at a seemingly random moment it will change color.

For that reason I recommend to tint both `layout.endIconTintList` and `drawable.tintList` with the same `ColorStateList`. Such as:

```
fun Context.fetchPrimaryColor(): Int {
    val array = obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.colorPrimary))
    val color = array.getColorOrThrow(0)
    array.recycle()
    return color
}

...

val states = ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf()), intArrayOf(fetchPrimaryColor()))
layout.setEndIconTintList(states)
drawable.setTintList(states)
```

---

Ultimately we get something like this:

[image: InputTextLayout with loading indicators]

with `android.R.attr.progressBarStyle` (medium) and `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall` respectively.

Comment: Nice write-up! Very useful

Comment: Great answer, thank you, it works. Just one note, you can use your custom colors instead of Android colors. You can do it like `requireContext().getColorStateList(R.color.yourcolor)` or `ContextCompat.getColorStateList(requireContext(), R.color.yourColor)` if you are using Compat libraries and just add the state list with `layout.setEndIconTintList(states)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir for this declarative explanation with a code sample.

Comment: How to use **getProgressBarDrawable** ?

Comment: What if don't want tinting at all. Why google assume everyone wants tint?

Comment: I've figured it out - with `setEndIconTintList(null)` - works like a charm... for now (lol).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **`ProgressIndicator`** provided by the Material Components Library.

In your layout just use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinputlayout"
        ...>
        
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          .../>
        
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Then define the `ProgressIndicator` using:

```
    ProgressIndicatorSpec progressIndicatorSpec = new ProgressIndicatorSpec();
    progressIndicatorSpec.loadFromAttributes(
            this,
            null,
            R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_ProgressIndicator_Circular_Indeterminate);

    progressIndicatorSpec.circularInset = 0; // Inset
    progressIndicatorSpec.circularRadius =
            (int) dpToPx(this, 10); // Circular radius is 10 dp.

    IndeterminateDrawable progressIndicatorDrawable =
            new IndeterminateDrawable(
                    this,
                    progressIndicatorSpec,
                    new CircularDrawingDelegate(),
                    new CircularIndeterminateAnimatorDelegate());
```

Finally apply the drawable to the TextInputLayout:

```
 textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM);
 textInputLayout.setEndIconDrawable(progressIndicatorDrawable);
```

[image]

It is the util method to convert to dp:

```
public static float dpToPx(@NonNull Context context, @Dimension(unit = Dimension.DP) int dp) {
    Resources r = context.getResources();
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

You can easily customize the `circularRadius` and the `indicatorColors` and all other attributes defined in the `ProgressIndicator`:

```
    progressIndicatorSpec.indicatorColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.progress_colors);
    progressIndicatorSpec.growMode = GROW_MODE_OUTGOING;
```

with this array:

```
<integer-array name="progress_colors">
    <item>@color/...</item>
    <item>@color/....</item>
    <item>@color/....</item>
</integer-array>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha02`**.

Comment: how to hide this progress ??

Answer (score 3):

This question already has a good answer, however, I would like to post a more concise and simpler solution. If you use androidx you have a class that inherits Drawable - CircularProgressDrawable, so you can use it. This some piece of code I use in my project:

```
CircularProgressDrawable drawable = new CircularProgressDrawable(requireContext());
        drawable.setStyle(CircularProgressDrawable.DEFAULT);
        drawable.setColorSchemeColors(Color.GREEN);
 inputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener(view -> {
            inputLayout.setEndIconDrawable(drawable);
            drawable.start();
//some long running operation starts...
}
```

Result:
[image: here is how result looks like]

Comment: You need androidx.swiperefreshlayout for CircularProgressDrawable, it's not part of regular androidx. Much simpler solution though.